# jquery bootstrap selectpicker blur after using the toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have almost 15 text fields in my form. Every select call binding next select picker. I want to blur (**unfocus**) on the select picker input text field after using the toggle.

```
$('#drpSubModels').selectpicker("refresh");
$('#drpSubModels').selectpicker('toggle');
```

[image]

I'm trying for this as like that;

```
  setTimeout(function () {
        $(".form-control").blur()
    }, 1000);
```

But mostly, it didn't work. If I set the setTimeout value under 1000, it never works.

*(Meanwhile, setTimeout is not a good solution because I'll use this form in a mobile app as Hybrid. When I use the toggle, every time calls the keyboard and If the blur is work, keyboard immediately showing and disappearing on the screen, If setTimeout not working, the keyboard appearing permanently)*

---

onload, ontoggle etc. no any chance..

```
$('.selectpicker').on('onload', function () {
    $(".form-control").blur();
});
```

---

Is there a method or way to blur the select picker input text after using the toggle?

**Libraries**;

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved when I handled the focus event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var blurState = false;

    $('.bs-searchbox .form-control').on('focus', function () {
        if (!blurState) {
            $(this).blur();
            blurState = true;
        }
    });

    $('.selectpicker').on('hide.bs.select', function () {
        blurState = false;
    });
});
```